# Pointer to pointer as a function parameter

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int f(int x, int *py, int **ppz) {
    int y, z;
    **ppz += 1;
    z = **ppz;
    *py += 2;
    y = *py;
    x += 3;
    return x + y + z;
}

int main(void) {
    int c = 4;

    printf("f(): %d\n", f(c, &c, &&c));
    printf("c:   %d\n", c);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How can I access `**ppz` correctly, because so I get an error message: "label 'c' used, but not defined".

Comment: You want to modify an `int`, so the parameter should be `int *`, not `int **`

Comment: `&c` is a pointer *expression*. You cannot create a pointer to an expression, it has no address.. Besides, the `&&` operator has a different meaning.

Comment: FYI, the error message about “label 'c' used” is because `&&name` is a GCC extension to refer to statement labels (which are normally the targets of `goto` statements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `int**` is a pointer to an `int*`. You need to create a variable of type `int*` to be able to pass a pointer to it somewhere. Here is what you should do:

```
int main(void) {
    int c = 4;
    int* pc = &c;

    printf("f(): %d\n", f(c, pc, &pc));
    printf("c:   %d\n", c);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Refer @ikegami's answer for an explanation of the proper use of a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: That code is not likely to ever be correct for a function that requires an `int**`. It works in this particular case, but only because it makes no sense to use `int**` there.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Yes, you're right that the point is not to modify the original int but rather the value of the int*. But, I think the OP's question is more of a pedagogical example meant to show the functionality/operation of pointers rather than the proper use of the double pointers in the proper sense

Comment: Re "*How do you mean?*", Why do you think your code would be acceptable if `f` changed `*ppz` (the only reason for `int **ppz`)

Comment: Re "*I think the OP's question is more of a pedagogical example*", I think you're right, and that you failed to teach how `int**` is properly used.

Answer (score 1):

You want to modify a variable of type `int`, so the parameter should be `int *`, not `int **`.

You'd use `int **` if you wanted to modify a variable of type `int *` variable. That's not the case here.

For example,

```
void f(int **pp) {
    *pp = malloc(10);
}

int main(void) {
    int *p;
    f(&p);
    // ...
    free(p);
}
```